# Volume through glass in Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Is there a way to make volume visible through a glass object in eevee?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Just use this node arrangement for your glass. Pay attention to the blend modes highlighted on the right:

[image: Glass]

EDIT - My bad, I didn't see you wanted a refraction component. Adding it is easy, just add  a Refraction BSDF and use another Mix Shader to combine it with the existing glass shader. See below (Note - I used a sphere in the image because the gem doesn't refract so well - surprisingly).

[image: Refract]

Comment: Thanks. This method is better than what I had, but I was hoping I'd be able to use refraction as well.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by refraction? I'm sure it's possible - IOR of the fresnel is a refraction index. Also, I noticed it looks way better if you apply smooth shading to the gem.

Comment: The objects seen through the lens are not distorted, as they should be if seen through curved glass.

Comment: I updated my answer to include refraction.